# How can I pass proxy credentials onto applications that don't support it?

Tags: windows-7, proxy

I work as local IT support in an environment with strict web filtering that is outside of our control. They also route traffic through a proxy. We regularly have applications that are either command line or don't have options to enter proxy details but still need to check resources online. Is there any way proxy credentials can be passed onto these applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

If the client does not support a proxy you can't pass credentials on to it (well you can, but they will be ignored).

What you may be able to do would be to implement a transparent proxy, which intercepts all web requests and pushes them through a proxy.  This needs to be done at a router, so doing so will depend on your network - if you can set up a box running Linux as a router / firewall, you may be able to use "[tproxy](http://www.balabit.com/support/community/products/tproxy)"   (OpenWRT and presumeably other similar distros can do it on some basic routers, but setting it up is not always trivial).

I've not played with it, but it looks like you can do something similar on a [CISCO](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/papers/cisco_squid_wccp.html).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I never thought to route our traffic through a VM so I'll play with that. Our overall department limits our access to switches and routers, so I wouldn't be able to alter anything on our physical gear :(